# how to configure data labels in a numpy array for training a Keras model?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras, training-data

I'm trying to implement Keras for my first time (so sorry for the dumb question) as part of a wider project to make an AI that learns to play connect 4. As part of this, I pass a NN a 6*7 grid and it outputs an array of 7 values giving the probabilities to pick for each column in the game. Here is the output of the Model.summary() method for a bit more detail:

```
______________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
flatten (Flatten)            (None, 42)                0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 20)                860       
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 20)                420       
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 7)                 147       
=================================================================
Total params: 1,427
Trainable params: 1,427
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
_________________________________________________________________
```

the model will give (at the moment random) predictions when i pass it numpy arrays of shape (1, 6, 7), however, when i try to train the model with an array of shape (221, 6, 7) for the data and an array of shape (221, 7) for the labels i get this error:

*ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_2 to have shape (1,) but got array with shape (7,)*

This is the code I use to train the model (which outputs (221, 6, 7) and (221, 7)):

```
board_tensor = np.array(full_board_list)
print(board_tensor.shape)
label_tensor = np.array(full_label_list)
print(label_tensor.shape)
self.model.fit(board_tensor, label_tensor)
```

this is the code I use to define the model:

```
self.model = keras.Sequential([
             keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(6, 7)),
             keras.layers.Dense(20, activation=tf.nn.relu),
             keras.layers.Dense(20, activation=tf.nn.relu),
             keras.layers.Dense(7, activation=tf.nn.softmax)])
self.model.compile(optimizer=tf.train.AdamOptimizer(),
                   loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
                   metrics=['accuracy'])
```

(the model is part of an AI object so that it could be compared to other types of AI objects)
This is the code which successfully predicts a batch of size 1, generated from by a two dimensional list representing the board (it outputs (1, 6, 7) and (1, 7)):

```
input_tensor = np.array(board.board)
input_tensor = np.expand_dims(input_tensor, 0)
print(input_tensor.shape)
probability_distribution = self.model.predict(input_tensor)
print(probability_distribution.shape)
```

I realise that the error is probably due to a lack of understanding on my part as to what the methods in Keras expect to be given; so as a little side-note, does anyone have any good, thorough learning resources which really get you to understand what each method is doing (ie. not just telling you which code to type in to make an image recogniser) that would be understandable to people new to Keras and Tensorflow like me?

thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` loss, which takes integer labels (not one-hot encoded ones), while your labels are one-hot encoded. This is why you get an error.

The easiest way to fix it is to change loss to `categorical_crossentropy`.